# How to remove() the append() child element with Using jQuery on the page?

Tags: jquery

Base html code:

```
<div class="items">
     <div class="item">
         <span>item text</span>
         <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     </div>
</div>
```

append child element code (jQuery):

```
$('.items').append('<div class="item"><span>'+ text + '</span><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>');
```

remove element code (jQuery):

```
$('.items .item i').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Child (item) to be added based HTML Code, This Child will be deleted By "remove element code".
But Other children to be added By "append child element code" not deleted!

please guide me ...

Comment: You need to rerun your remove element code every time you append a new element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to  use **[`event delegation`](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** since item added dynamically otherwise event handler not get attached to the dynamically added dom elements.

```
$('.items').on('click','.item i',function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
    // or  $(this).closest('.item').remove();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, Command "parent" in the source code I forget in the question.
However, can not remove elements added.
I edited the question.

Comment: @MONJE : did you tried `$('.items').on('click','.item i',function(){`

Comment: Thank you so much. Problem with "$('.items').on('click','.item i',function(){"  solved.

Comment: @MONJE : glad to help :)

Comment: Just be sure with this method not to use the event.stopPropagation because then the event won't bubble up to the next elements

Answer (score 1):

Event handlers like click are assigned to all *current* matching elements. Since future elements didn't exist it doesn't assign the event handler. All you need to do is rerun your remove element function every time you add a new element so it assigns the event handler to that element. Or if you want it to be cleaner add the event handler to the specific new element like this

```
$('<div class="item"><span>'+ text + '</span><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>').appendTo(".items").children("i").click(function(){
$(this).parent().remove();
});
```

That would be in place of your current append function

Comment: Thank for pay attention :)  problem  solved with the help of "Pranav C Balan"